# SharPoint Online Modern Communication Site: fail to create page template, REST error

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, communication-site

I'm building a SharePoint online communication site, but when I try to save a page as template or publish a page using defined page templates saved before, it gives me the following error:

```
REST error Error with code -2147024809, System.ArgumentException due to Inner-Message: Value does not fall within the expected range. Exception-Message: [HTTP]:400 - Bad Request [CorrelationId]:e3c3a69f-a019-b000-a2dc-4a074ad75594 [Version]:16.0.0.20913 at Error: Inner-Message: Value does not fall within the expected range. Exception-Message: [HTTP]:400 - Bad Request [CorrelationId]:e3c3a69f-a019-b000-a2dc-4a074ad75594 [Version]:16.0.0.20913 at new t (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_6aa2fc520591708ec0b2ff861ee40b72.js:1:329724) at Function.e._getOdataRestApiError (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.sp-pages-statemanager_en-us_e9b99b9a155c33296e29.js:1:20936) at https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.sp-pages-statemanager_en-us_e9b99b9a155c33296e29.js:1:23643}
```

does someone have idea how i can fix this error? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar case for your reference：

[[SharePoint Online] Modern page creation failure with custom template and content type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/200333/sharepoint-online-modern-page-creation-failure-wit.html)

Of course, you could try to following steps to save page as template:

1. Connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell and set **denyaddandcustomizepages** of the site to **false**.

   $adminUPN="[admin]@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com"

   $userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."

   Connect-SPOService -Url https://[tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential

   set-sposite https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[communication/team] -denyaddandcustomizepages $false
2. We can save the site (**modern team site and communication site**) as the site template by visiting **/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx** page.

[image]

3. Then, you can access **/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx**
   page and view your template.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Unfortunately I don't have the admin access to the website..

Comment: Hi, Leonie. Enable save site as template on SharePoint online. User account needs to have Full permission to access the site.